# How do I store an array in a PSQL, where it is passed as a parameter $1 to the db query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, arrays, psql

I am passing a one-dimensional array of three strings to the function, it looks like this going in:

```
[ '#masprofundo', '#massensual', '#eclectic' ]
```

The data column is declared thus:

```
 tags TEXT []
```

This is my function:

```
const query = `INSERT INTO posts (posted_at, message, link, tags)
                VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP($1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), $2, $3, ARRAY [$4])
                RETURNING tags;`;
const params = [timestamp, message, link, tags];
```

Now, postgres believes I want to insert an array containing one item, which is a string of all the values in my tags array. It looks like this:

```
{ tags: [ '{"#masprofundo","#massensual","#eclectic"}' ] }
```

What I want to know is, how do I prevent this behaviour, where postGres adds an unnecessary extra layer of quotation marks and parentheses? For further clarification; this is what the row looks like in my terminal.

```
{"{\"#masprofundo\",\"#massensual\",\"#eclectic\"}"}
```

I have looked at the docs, and tried a dozen variations on ARRAY[$4]. From what I can see, the docs do not elaborate on inserting arrays as variables. Is there some destructuring that needs to happen? The arrays I pass will be of varying size, and sometimes empty.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're passing the JS array as an element of a declared DB array. Have you tried just $4 instead of ARRAY[$4] ?

Comment: Thanks a million, you solved it